Masking and SortOrder Text in 2D game
I'm creating a 2d game in Unity with simple cards that can be dragged from hand to be played in the middle of the game space. The cards are created from multiple sprite GameObjects along with their associated children.  In addition to that, the cards will need to have text that can be modified in script (each individual card can be modified by game events, so would need to vary from prefabs.)  The text on the cards can't be static sprites, so I'm trying to find a solution that works.
First idea was to use a TextMeshPro, but I can't use that on a sprite.  The sprite renderer and mesh are mutually exclusive.  That means I can't use the 2d Unity Sort Order to manage its visibility.  The text will either be occluded by every sprite object, or will float on top of the sprite objects.  No in-between, which for a card game is useless.  I've tried creating sprite or canvas objects and then adding the TMP as a child object, but I've not found a way to get it to act as a 2d object for purposes of sorting.
Second idea was to use a TextMeshPro (UI) on a canvas.  For purposes of dragging the card around and stacking them correctly using the Unity Sort Order for 2d objects works perfectly.  However, I'd like to be able to mask the cards as a special effect.  For example, create a "burning" effect that travels up the card, or a scanning "pulse" that masks the card from a center in an expanding circle.  All of the sprite objects mask as you'd expect, but as the TMP is a UI object, it ignores sprite masks.
All the documentation I can find about this is wildly out of date.  Am I using the wrong type of objects?  Is there a way to mask the TMP (UI) that I'm missing?
Current implementation code is using TMP (UI).  In the Update I have the following:
        if (beingPlayed && !moving && countdownToBurn > 0)
        {
            countdownToBurn -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (countdownToBurn <= 0){
                burning = true;
                burnMask = GameObject.Instantiate<SpriteMask>(stage.CircleSpriteMask);
                burnMask.sprite = stage.CirclePrefab.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
                burnMask.transform.position = ZoneConfig.playLocation;
                burnMask.transform.localScale = Vector3.zero;
            }
        }

        if (burning)
        {
            burnMask.transform.localScale = new Vector3(
                burnMask.transform.localScale.x + ZoneConfig.cardBurnScaleAdder,
                burnMask.transform.localScale.y + ZoneConfig.cardBurnScaleAdder,
                burnMask.transform.localScale.z + ZoneConfig.cardBurnScaleAdder);
            if (burnMask.transform.localScale.x >= ZoneConfig.cardBurnScaleAdder * ZoneConfig.cardBurnScaleMult)
            {
                stage.PlayCard(thisCard);
                thisCard.DestroyCard();
                Destroy(burnMask);
            }
        }

Some basics from that, when a player releases the card, it floats to the center of the screen and sits there for a second or two (countdownToBurn), then it creates a spriteMask from prefab (burnMask) that starts small, then grows by a preset amount on each update (ZoneConfig.cardBurnScaleAdder).  Once it hits a certain threshold (ZoneConfig.cardBurnScaleMult) the mask is larger than the card and is safe to be "played", and then destroyed.
All of the above is working, except the TMP (UI) on the card isn't being affected by the mask.
Thanks all!

If I understood you correctly, you basically want your text to behave as a normal object to make it part of the sprite and not be a Ui object?
I have a solution for you.

First create a new canvas.
Set the render mode to World Spaec.
RectTransform (Canvas): set position to (0,0,0) so you can find it
RectTransform (Canvas): set width/height (I try 60*80 and it's looks fine)
RectTransform (Canvas): set scale to (0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
Now create your text mesh pro on the canvas

It's will looks like that when the circle order in layer is higert then the capsule and the text is child of the capsule.

I would appreciate it if you marked the answer if it solved your problem or let me know if this was not your intention.

Thanks for the quick reply!  I've just created a canvas object through the Hierarchy.  This is the object that was created: 
I don't see anything in there that would allow me to set the canvas to render to World Space.  Is this an option that has recently changed, or the wording on it altered?  I saw this in other answers with similar questions, but the dates on them were all old.  I wonder if perhaps this wisdom is based on an out-dated version of Unity?

@JFRApplications You can only do this on a root canvas not on nested ones, your images indicates that this is a nested canvas

Thanks @derHugo that's fixed the first problem.  Okay, so the canvas can't be a child of any game objects.  Got it.  Next problem.  Canvas Text In the little animation, the text reading "Some Text" is a TMP child object of a canvas object rendered in world space.  There's also a circular sprite mask, which you can see the text doesn't respect.  I've added a sprite renderer to the canvas and set mask interaction to "Visible outside". The card sprites work fine, but not text.

Just as a mention before anyone suggests it, I've also tried adding the text as a component to the canvas rather than a child object.  The behavior is the same.  Also, in both the example gif above and the test I did with the TMP component, the 3d text object didn't respect the canvas' sorting, so it's no better than a TMP object on its own.  I'm so sorry if I'm missing something crucial here.  I promise I'm not trying to be dense--but none of the above is working.

@JFRApplications the canvas can very well be a child of any GameObject as long as there isn't any other Canvas further up the hierarchy

Okay got it.  Any help on the sprite mask, though?

Thanks @derHugo, this has led me round-about to the correct solution.  I've posted it above--and can accept it as the answer tomorrow.

Found a solution that works for me:
The TMP object can't be masked in 3d space as far as I can tell.
This needs to be performed simultaneously with both a sprite mask for the sprite objects and a canvas image mask for the text objects (As TMP(UI) objects).  Further, the canvas image mask has to be the parent of the text objects.
To make this work, I need a very specific stacking of objects:  Canvas rendered in world space, which holds the sprite objects and an image object that (at least to begin with) has nothing on it.
Then, when the card is ready to be masked, create a sprite mask and an image on the canvas image object that match, and create a mask component to the image object.
This is bulky and annoying, but it does work.  I need to keep the sprite mask and the image object in-step to make the masking appear clean to the user.

why go with SpriteRenderer and a sprite mask at all then? Couldn't you move this into an UI Image component under the same canvas as well?

I'm using a bunch of sprite-based stuff in the rest of the game, such as sprite animations.  After some searching, I guess it's possible to do that on the UI layer as well, but that has its own problems.

Or, to be more succinct: the text is only one of many things I'm going to be doing as part of the special effects.  So far, it's the only part of the effects that didn't work the way I expected it to with the tools I currently understand.

Yeah I guess then your way of replicating the same masks for both systems (sprites and UI) is probably the way to go here .. even though a bit uncanny
